# why is there a memory leak in the SimpleEKDemo code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, eventkit

When profiling the [SimpleEKDemo application from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160) I note there are some memory leaks.

One of the leaks is __NSArrayM which has 3 lines in the Leaked Blocks history, a Malloc/Assign/Release.

Question - can someone point out the root cause issue here?  (I'm trying learn how to take Instruments output of where a leaky object was created, and then from there work out root cause, so this would be really useful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will notice that when you run the demo with leaks that there is a leak in `viewDidLoad` (responsible frame). If you switch to `Call Tree` detail and if you have enabled `Invert Call Tree`, you will see a leak associated with the call `+[NSArray new]`. If you open that a bit, you will see `initWithArray` which is called in the `RootViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`. The problem bit is,

```
self.eventsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:0];
```

`eventsList` is a `retain`ed property so the object created has a retain count of 2. However it is only `release`d once either through the `release` in `dealloc` or through reassignment of `eventsList`. YOu will have to autorelease this object.

```
self.eventsList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:0] autorelease];
```

Once fixed, you shouldn't get any errors.

Comment: oh - so you mean if you have a property with "retain", then you should be careful to create a variable via "alloc" for it as it effectively implies two (2) retain counts not one (1)?  Is that correct?  (if yes - then I've learn a good lesson, I didn't realise this)

Comment: `alloc` creates an instance with a retain count 1 but the assignment to a `retain` property adds a `retain` call to the instance making the retain count 2.

Comment: ok thanks - I think I have to review a whole heap of code now on this basis  :)